# Gluon field calculations

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

How do I calculate the qcd covariant derivative I can’t figure out the value of the gluon field I have tried many sites on the internet

This equation shows the covariant derivative:
$$
D_\mu = \partial_\mu \pm i g_s t_a \mathcal A^a_\mu
$$

What is the value of $\mathcal A$?

Comment: This question is unclear

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no meaningful previous research effort.

Answer (score 1):

The gluon field doesn't have a value. In the path integral language, it's an integration variable. In the Hamiltonian language, it's a (gauge-variant) local operator acting on Hilbert space.